# Running python test suite from a python script (programmatrically)?

Tags: python, cpython

You can run the Python test suite (https://docs.python.org/3/library/test.html) from the command-line using:

```
$ python -m test
```

How do you run it from a python script?

```
import test

# test.run_all_tests() ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As taken from the `__main__.py` file:

```
from test.libregrtest import main
main()
```

Keep in mind using this outside of internal CPython development is discouraged as the code may change without notice.